# Set a default value for an execution field of airflow sensors

Tags: airflow

My problem is fairly simple if you know Airflow. I would like to set a default value other then None for the execution field `execution_timeout`. I was wondering if that was possible and if it is how to do it.
If it's not possible is the only way to do this to  set `execution_timeout=timedelta(hours=2)` for every sensor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it once in `default_args` and then it will be the default values for all sensor/operators in your DAG, you can also override in a specific operator/sensor:

```
default_args = {
    'execution_timeout': timedelta(hours=2),
}

with DAG(
        dag_id="my_dag",
        default_args=default_args,
        ...,
) as dag:
    op1 = MyOperator(task_id="task_op_1")
    se1 = MySensor(task_id="task_sensor_1")
    op1 >> se1
    op2 = MyOperator(task_id="task_op_2")
    se2 = MySensor(task_id="task_sensor_2", execution_timeout=timedelta(hours=1)) # override
    op2 >> se2
```

In the above example `task_op_1`, `task_sensor_1`, `task_op_2` will have `execution_timeout` of 2 hours while `task_sensor_2` will have `execution_timeout` of 1 hour.

Note that for `Airflow>=2.3.0` it is also possible to define global `execution_timeout` by setting [`default_task_execution_timeout`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1c680e4b345f4c2f6e578a133af91d3a812f6471/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L157-L160) in airflow.cfg with

Comment: Thank you for your answer,


My problem is that I specifically want to set a default value for sensors only. Default_args would apply to sensors and operators which doesn't help me much unfortunately.

Comment: On a specific DAG or in your whole Airflow cluster?

Comment: On my whole Airflow cluster

Comment: Then you should use cluster policy: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/cluster-policies.html#cluster-policies you can check if the operator is sensor and in that case set value for `execution_timeout`. it's not 100% what you asked but this is the closest thing you can get.

Comment: So I tried to implement this, but it's not working. My suspicion is that my task policy function is never called. I am using Airflow 1.10 and I was wondering how the task policy was called? Is the name of the task policy important? Does the task policy function needs to take a task object as a parameter or can it take a BaseSensorOperator?